# Simple Title not showing up in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, uitabbaritem

I have looked at all of the similar/related questions, but none either a) are exactly my problem or 2) the solutions just don't work.

In my appDelegate.m I have in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
JCGRootNavigationController *rnc = [[JCGRootNavigationController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = rnc;`
```

JCGRootNavigationController is a subclass of UINavigationController

```
@interface JCGRootNavigationController : UINavigationController`
```

In JCGRootNavigationController.m:

```
@implementation JCGRootNavigationController

-(instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"MY TITLE";    
    return self;
}
```

And the title just won't display.  I see the Navigation Bar, but no title.  Looks like lots of people over the years have had this same problem.  Maybe a simple answer will help clear up all of the confusing.  This is so incredibly frustrating.

Comment: You need to set the title property of the view controller that the navigation controller is displaying. The title you are setting would only show up if you put your JCGRootNavigationController inside yet another UINavigationController.

Comment: Did you try `self.title`?

Comment: I did try `self.title` that did not work either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UINavigationController automatically shows the title of the UIViewController subclass it is displaying.  It does so by looking at the navigationItem.title property of that UIViewController or UIViewController subclass.  Basically UINavigationController doesn't have a title.

Answer (score 27):

When working with a Storyboard, setting the `title` of the `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` does not seem to add that title to the Navigation Controller, as other answers suggest.

Instead, find the `UINavigationItem` that is likely alongside your View Controller object in the Storyboard hierarchy. Set this Navigation Item's `title` to apply that title to the Navigation Controller.

[image: Navigation Item on Storyboard[1]]

Comment: **OH. MY. $DEITY.** Thanks. I wasn't expecting iOS to ignore my view controller's title.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks believesInSanta, While I cannot find this explicitly stated in apple documentation anywhere, I have to go with this being the answer. **UINavigationController doesn't have a title.**

To get the title to work, back in appDelegate.h I added:

```
JCGTableViewController *tvc = [[JCGTableViewController alloc] init];
JCGRootNavigationController *rnc = [[JCGRootNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tvc];
self.window.rootViewController = rnc;
```

Where JCGTableViewController is another subclass I added.  As you can probably tell, it is a subclass of UITableViewController.

In JCGTableViewController I overrode init to:

```
-(instancetype) init {

    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        self.title = @"TVC";
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }

    return self;
}
```

While I used a tableViewController, I imagine you can add any view to the NavigationController and set the properties that way.  I will play around with that today.

Thanks all!